# how to compare 2 json in python

Tags: python

How to compare 2 json objects in python below are the sample json.

```
sample_json1={
    {
       "globalControlId": 72,
       "value": 0,
       "controlId": 2
   },
   {
       "globalControlId": 77,
       "value": 3,
       "controlId": 7
   }
}

sample_json2={
    {
       "globalControlId": 72,
       "value": 0,
       "controlId": 2
   },
   {
       "globalControlId": 77,
       "value": 3,
       "controlId": 7
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why `if sample_json1 == sample_json2:` would not be sufficient???

Comment: The "json" samples that you've written are not valid. You have to give us more context/working code if you want any help.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that the usual comparison working properly

```
import json
x = json.loads("""[
    {
       "globalControlId": 72,
       "value": 0,
       "controlId": 2
   },
   {
       "globalControlId": 77,
       "value": 3,
       "controlId": 7
   }
]""")

y = json.loads("""[{"value": 0, "globalControlId": 72,"controlId": 2}, {"globalControlId": 77, "value": 3, "controlId": 7 }]""")

x == y # result: True
```

Answer (score 4):

these are not valid JSON / Python objects, because array / list literals are inside `[]` instead of `{}`:

**UPDATE**: to compare list of dictionaries (serialized JSON array of objects), while ignoring the order of list items, the lists need to be **sorted or converted to sets**:

```
sample_json1=[{"globalControlId": 72, "value": 0, "controlId": 2},
              {"globalControlId": 77, "value": 3, "controlId": 7}]
sample_json2=[{"globalControlId": 77, "value": 3, "controlId": 7},
              {"globalControlId": 77, "value": 3, "controlId": 7}, # duplicity
              {"globalControlId": 72, "value": 0, "controlId": 2}]

# dictionaries are unhashable, let's convert to strings for sorting
sorted_1 = sorted([repr(x) for x in sample_json1])
sorted_2 = sorted([repr(x) for x in sample_json2])
print(sorted_1 == sorted_2)

# in case the dictionaries are all unique or you don't care about duplicities,
# sets should be faster than sorting
set_1 = set(repr(x) for x in sample_json1)
set_2 = set(repr(x) for x in sample_json2)
print(set_1 == set_2)
```

Comment: this wont work if the order changes example for the below example it fails

Comment: sample_json1=[{"globalControlId": 72,
               "value": 0,
               "controlId": 2},
              {"globalControlId": 77,
               "value": 3,
               "controlId": 7}]
sample_json2=[
              {"globalControlId": 77,
               "value": 3,
               "controlId": 7},
               {"globalControlId": 72,
               "value": 0,
               "controlId": 2}]

Comment: comparison should be success even if the order changes please help me here

Comment: updated according to comments

Comment: It seems your solution does not handle the nested jsons(json trees)

Comment: @zochhuana does the other solution handle nested jsons? i wouldn't count on it even if it does.. if you need to do deep comparison, one of the top links in google is [Deep Equality Test for Nested Python Structures](https://gist.github.com/samuraisam/901117)